# Adsense test screen resolution

Tags: google-adsense, mobile, resolution, screen-size, desktop

According to adsense, they want to see content above-the-fold and not have ads push content down below the fold. In order for me to set all my CSS measurements right, I'm curious as to what screen resolutions adsense uses to evaluate a website with adsense code before determining how much one will be credited and/or if policies have been violated. I'm asking for both users of desktop computers and users of mobile websites since I have a website designed for each category.

Comment: Good question!! Not sure Google tells us. But hopefully someone would have some ideas. I use my HP Netbook as for the standard for the desktop when I do my work since I do my work on the Netbook. Otherwise, I am dependent upon Chrome to spoof a mobile device. It would be nice for us good doers to know what limits there are so that we meet them.